# read json and convert it into csv in mule 3

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

Below json i am getting from one of the system. Now i have to read the payload.d.FailureRecord.CUError[0].ErrorRecords and convert the ErrorRecords into CSV but i am getting error even not able to read the ErrorRecords.

Error: 500 Exception while executing.

payload:

```
    {
    "d": {
    "FailureRecord": {
      "RequestId": "15",
      "GId": "23",
      "APIError": null,
      "GUError": null,
      "CUError": [
        {
          "CampaignId": "CreditCard",
          "ErrorRecords": "Case Id,Loan Account Number,External Key,Product Flag,Loan Type,EMI Amount,Overdue Charges,Reason for Bounce,Instrument Type,Last Mode of Payment,Registered Bank Name,LoanFromDuration,Balance Tenure,Number of EMIs Pending,Amount Financed,Number of Advance EMI,Sales Point Name,Principal Outstanding,Representation Status,Region,OPS Hold Status,Pre Due Identifer,Name,Additional Number 1,Additional Number 2,Other Number,Alternate Number 1,Alternate Number 2,Primary Email,Primary Mobile No,Address Line 1,Address Line 2,Address Line 3,Landmark,City,State,Pincode
    5009D000002dOwCQAU,12563550,,,Education,38383838383838,8700.0,Hier Issues,,Cash,Maha Bank,2020-03-24,,13.0,,,,0.0,false,,,,NESHU BALA,9803723933,9833583336,9820467890,9000000000,8111111111,a@a.com,9820468148,,,,,,,
    5009D000002dXgXQAU,10285237,,,TWO WHEELER LOANS,0.0,0.0,FUNDS INSUFFICIENT.,AUTO-DEBIT,AUTO-DEBIT,PUNJAB NATIONAL BANK,2017-04-05,,36.0,,,,,false,,,,PINKY BEGAM,98369703,9819055187,96666666666,9819055678,,pinky.begam1988@gmail.com,8451942332,,,,,,,
    5009D000002dXgYQAU,13587404,,,TWO WHEELER LOANS,4249.0,22378.0,FUNDS INSUFFICIENT.,AUTO-DEBIT,AUTO-DEBIT,IDBI BANK LTD,2017-05-05,,36.0,,,,,false,,,,PANDHARINATH DANGAL PATIL,9699301664,9800000001,,,,pandharinathpatil@gmail.com,7016407268,,,,,,,
    5009D000002dXgmQAE,10490959,,,TWO WHEELER LOANS,1800.0,0.0,FUNDS INSUFFICIENT.,AUTO-DEBIT,AUTO-DEBIT,BOI-BANK OF INDIA,2017-05-05,,36.0,,,,0.0,false,,,,ANVARKHAN ABBASKHAN PATHAN,9714997807,,00001111111,9111111111,8111111111,nomail@nomail.com,9714997807,,,,,,,
    5009D000002dXguQAE,10024923,,,TWO WHEELER LOANS,1644.0,32060.0,FUNDS INSUFFICIENT.,AUTO-DEBIT,AUTO-DEBIT,SBI STATE BANK OF INDIA,2017-04-05,,36.0,,,,,false,,,,SANJAYBHAI KHUMABHAI MACHHI,9924193957,,,,,sanjaymachhi676@gmail.com,9924193957,,,,,,,
    "
       }
      ]
    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Please post the complete error with all details from the log.

Comment: Looks like you don't need to 'convert' it into CSV, it is already a CSV. You just need to write ErrorRecords' value into a file.

Answer (score 0):

First, the JSON is invalid because it contains new line characters in the ErrorRecords. As @JorgeGarcia said, the value of ErrorRecords is already a CSV file. It needs to be escaped replacing them by the escape sequence `\n`, to be valid JSON.

It is not a good idea to cram a format into another format, though I have seen it many times.

Then you can use the [read()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-runtime/3.9/dataweave-language-introduction#read) DataWeave to parse the value of ErrorRecords as JSON.

For example:

```
<dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
  <dw:input-payload mimeType="application/json" />
    <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
        %output application/java
        ---
        read(payload.d.FailureRecord.CUError[0].ErrorRecords, "application/csv")
        ]]>     
    </dw:set-payload>
</dw:transform-message>
```

That will return the list of records to be processed.